# Excel Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below excel spreadsheet (image below) and would like to find the value in the area D2 to K26 based on changing the inputs found in cells N1, N2, and N3, how do I do this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(A:K,MATCH(N1,A:A,0)+MATCH(N2,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(N1,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(N1,A:A,0)+COUNTIFS(A:A,N1)-1))-1,MATCH(N3,1:1,0))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.